# Tag Synonym Request: [appengine] -> [google-app-engine]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Currently there are:

- **10** questions tagged with [[appengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appengine)]
- **4072** questions tagged as [[google-app-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine)]

All of the 10 [appengine] questions currently relates to Google App Engine. I think it would make sense to either retag those or create a synonymic link between those two tags, using [google-app-engine] as the master tag.

*Note:* I've checked the [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=synonym) page and it appears that this link hasn't been proposed yet.

*Note 2:* [appengine] tag has no wiki description. [google-app-engine] does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would retag `appengine` with `google-app-engine`.
What I don't like about appengine:

- it's not Google specific (although there's no other appengine available at the moment)
- it's without hyphen (should be app-engine<sup>*</sup>).

Google-app-engine has already a good common synonym: [gae](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-app-engine/synonyms)

<sup>* although stack overflow is tagged stackoverflow</sup>

Comment: What are the next steps to take in order to see this happen ?

Comment: @Em. patience and faith ;)

Comment: Thanks for this enlightened input ;-) I'll wait and keep hope, then...

Comment: @Em. I think this was completed

Comment: Proposed synonym at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-app-engine/synonyms and no more questions tagged appengine. Great!